# Why is it that when I call the constructor with Float.MIN_VALUE parameters, they are 0?

Tags: java, constructor, floating-point, joml

So I have a `Vector3f` class with a constructor:

```
public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
```

but when I call a constructor like this:

```
Vector3f max = new Vector3f(Float.MIN_VALUE, Float.MIN_VALUE, Float.MIN_VALUE);
```

and print the values to the console:

```
System.out.printf("x: %f, y: %f, z: %f\n", max.x, max.y, max.z);
```

the output will be

```
x: 0.000000, y: 0.000000, z: 0,000000
```

Why 0?

I used `Vector3f` from the Java OpenGL Math Library (JOML).

Comment: what did you expect? `Float.MIN_VALUE` is `2` to the power of `-149` or about `1.4E-45`, `%f` will display 6 digits after the decimal point, which is not enough... 45 digits are needed to see the first non-zero digit - try `%.45f` instead of `%f` (if only for testing) || [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#MIN_VALUE) of `MIN_VALUE`: "A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type float, ..."

Comment: and [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) of `Formatter` (for `%f`): "The number of digits in the result for the fractional part of m or a is equal to the precision. If the precision is not specified then the default value is 6."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be read in two completely different ways. I can answer them both.

### You expected it to be a very large negative number

That's just not what `MIN_VALUE` does. However, your confusion is understandable; `Integer.MIN_VALUE` **is** a very large negative number. The concept doesn't apply to float/double, as they have a value that represents negative infinity, which makes 'MIN_VALUE' in the sense of 'that number that is more negative than any other number `float` can represent' dubious / non-existent. The name is still unfortunate but java does not as a rule change things without a better reason than 'naming is confusing' to avoid backwards compatibility issues.

`Float.MIN_VALUE` represents the smallest *positive* representable float that is *not* equal to 0.

### I know that. But it prints 0!

The problem with float and double is that they are imprecise. If I hand you a postit and ask you to write 1/3 in decimal on it, you can't. You'll write 0.3333 and eventually run out of space. `double` and `float` are more or less the same, except in binary except decimal which is particularly painful because only stuff that fits in 2s can be accurately represented. We can do 1/10th in decimal (0.1, after all). In IEEE math that is as problematic as 1/3 is. Almost all fractions are problematic, except 1/2, 3/4th, etc. (the divisor a power of 2 - that's allright).

Let's see it in action:

```
double v = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(v == 1.0);
```

That prints... oof, `false`, which is wrong. `10 * 0.1` is obviously 1.0. But not in IEEE double math, evidently. Just like the sum of 3 postits with your best effort at 1/3 is not quite 1.0 (it'll be 0.9999999), we run into the same problem here.

### So how does that lead to print 0.0000?

Because the number is *stored* in binary but printed in decimal, and that results in some real wonky and unexpected behaviour if `println` would print the *exact* value. You'd get 0.9999999999999999999876 a lot, which is annoying. So, instead, printf/println just takes a *wild* stab in the dark and does some dubious rounding to make it all look right when none of it is.

This is why you should *never* just print a double. Instead use, as you are, `printf` / `String.format`. And specify how many digits you want, so you are in control of this necessary rounding. Without an explicit specifier, `%f` defaults to 6 digits. And 'the smallest non-zero positive float', rounded so that it fits in 6 digits, *is* 0.000000. You need *way* more digits to see this tiny, tiny number:

```
System.out.printf("%.99f\n", Float.MIN_VALUE);

> 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014012984643248170000000
```

That's how many digits you'd need to see it.

### Some important notes

- `float` is useless. `double` is just as fast or faster, takes just as much space in 99% of all cases (except `float[]` which is usually a bit smaller, but that's the only place where it tends to come up), and is less precise. Just don't use it - `double` instead.
- Another way to solve for this 'its inaccurate' issue is to not use floats/doubles at all. Find an atomic unit and represent those with int/long, or use BigDecimal. For GUI purposes the inaccuracy is usually worth it, though.

Comment: Excellent answer.  It’s worth noting that a lot of APIs, particularly Java2D APIs, require float arguments.  And I don’t know a lot about JIT compilation, but I’m pretty sure the x86 family still has 32-bit floating point instructions.

Comment: @VGR I'd assume, if they do, that they are _slower_. It still supports LOOPNZ and CMPXCHG opcodes too, but idiotically slow paths.